# Paypal Integration in a web store. Locking/Removing items that are in the cart?

Tags: php, paypal, shopping-cart

I have a website that list multiple items for sale. I would like to use paypal to sell stuff on it. The only problem is, when I have 1 item left, how can I avoid the clash if two people plan to buy it at the same time. Let's say Person A adds the item X to his cart. And after 30 second Person B adds the item to his Cart. Now person A is going to check out and is filling out his paypal information while Person B also presses checkout. How can I avoid that ? I know that I can remove the item from the listing the moment one of them is in the checkout stage, but again what If someone goes all the way to checkout page and just close his browser and never buy the item ? I appreciate it if anyone can suggest a solution that solves this issue and also give flexibility to people during shopping online.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a hosted button on PayPal.com, under step 2 of button creation you can track inventory.  Set the quantity to 1 or 2 or whatever you have in stock.  Later you can change the quantity in stock by going to My Saved Buttons -> Action -> Edit Button.

If it's a unique item, start with quantity 1 and simply remove the button from your website once sold.  People can't complete check out when there's 0 left in stock, so it's first come first served.